# Firestore rules. How to let users only modify themselves and certain values among them

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently making a simple social media app for android and I just started using firebase and it's quite a lot of information to take in. But I'm having a problem understanding the rules. My social media app has a custom currency and I don't want them to be able to edit the values of their currency only fields like date of birth, username, password, email, gender etc; I'm quite clueless on what I'm exactly supposed to do even after reading the docs. Any help is much appreciated.

This is my attempt at it but I being quite unsure how to restrict them from updating certain aspects of their profile.

```
    service cloud.firestore {
    match /user_profiles/{profileid} {
         allow update: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to that "allow":

```
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /user_profiles/{profileid} {
        allow update: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid && profileModel();
    }
    function profileModel() {
        // Currency must be the same value as before (avoid edition)
        return request.resource.data.currency == resource.data.currency
        // The new data provided must have "name" and "surname" properties
        && request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(["name", "surname"])
        // Some other possible restrictions
                 && request.resource.data.name is string
                 && request.resource.data.surname is string
                 // Age must be an integer
                 && request.resource.data.age is int
    }
  }
```

There are many other possibilities that you can check in the [Firestore Rules Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/)